# I'm having trouble finding the sequence generated by this function.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

$f(x)=\frac{1}{e^x(1-x)}$

I'm aware that $e^x$ generates $1,\frac{1}{1!},\frac{2}{2!},\frac{3}{3!}...$

And I think that $\frac{e^x}{(1-x)}$ generates $a_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{i!}}$

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by the sequence generated by a function?

Comment: @paulinho That's a standard definition $f\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$. For example, the sequence $\left(1,1,1,\dots\right)$ is generated by $f\left(x\right)=1+x+x^{2}+\dots=\frac{1}{1-x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\\\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n,|x|<1$$

Thus, the Maclaurin series of $f(x)$ is
$$f(x)=\frac{e^{-x}}{1-x}=\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right)\\=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\right)x^n,|x|<1$$and the required sequence is $\left\{\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\right)\right\}_{n=0}^\infty$.

Comment: Thank you! This absolutely solved it, a curious question though, does the fact that $|x|<1$ have any relevance while manipulating the sums?

Comment: @Casper $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ is convergent to $\frac1{1-x}$ only for $|x|<1$, although you can omit this detail for finding generating functions